# Flutter module communication with main app using Pigeon plugin

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, pigeon

I have a Flutter module imported into a main Flutter application. I'm trying to use the Pigeon plugin to call methods from my module to the native side of my main application. However, I'm facing issues with configuring Pigeon correctly.

Here's what I've done so far:
1- Created my message declaration file (message_api.dart) in my main application.
2- Generated the associated code (pigeon_api.dart for the Flutter side and pigeon_api.kt for the Android native side).
3- Initialized my APIs from the MainActivity of the native side (this is the standard configuration).

To allow the module to also call the methods created by Pigeon, I copied the pigeon_api.dart file into the Flutter part of my module. I then used it for standard method calls in my code.

The issue I'm facing is that when I debug, the code can't seem to link the pigeon_api.dart from my module to the pigeon_api.kt of the native side of my main application. Even though the channel name and the Pigeon version are identical.

Has anyone encountered this issue or can provide some guidance? I've been trying to find a solution for several days now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to invoke the method and if the channeling isn't setup correctly you will see error or warning logs on the console.

And remember to setup your API interface to the flutter engine. Example code:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        MyAPI.setUp(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, MyAPIImplementation())
    }
}
```